# Wordpress WPAllImport: Own PHP Function if array to string

Tags: php, arrays, wpallimport

My JSON import URL has a field, which sometimes contains a single text or an array.

JSON Array:

```
wp_u_umlaufart  
0   "Personal"
1   "Organisation"
```

Simple Text:

```
wp_u_umlaufart  "Organisation"
```

With the function I tried to check if it is an array, if yes then return this as string and if not then just the text.

My Function:

```
function my_array_convert( $content ) {
    if (is_array($content)) {
        $converted_arr = implode(",", $content);
        return $converted_arr;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

[image]

And this is my custom-field:
[image]

Unfortunately, only the texts arrive, an array is not returned.

I changed the function to:

```
function my_array_convert( $content ) {
    $obj = json_decode(json_encode($content), true);
    if (is_array($obj)) {
        $converted_arr = implode(",", $obj);
        return $converted_arr;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

WPIMPORT does not output this correctly, I have not found an error so far.

But if i put this in my php Sandbox it will work:

```
<?php

$content = ["Personal","Organisation"];

$obj = json_decode(json_encode($content), true);

echo is_array($obj) ? 'Yes Array' : 'No Array';

if (is_array($obj)) {
   $converted_arr = implode(",", $obj);
   echo $converted_arr;
} else {
   echo $content;
}

?>
```

Comment: You function only gets _text_ passed into it, WP All Import has no knowledge of your data actually being JSON at this point. You need to _decode_ the JSON, and _then_ check if the result was an array, or a plain string.

Comment: We do not want textual details provided as screenshots.  Please [edit] your question to clarify what `$content` is.